# Opposite of org-narrow-to-subtree

Tags: org-mode

I have an org document and I go to one of it's subheading and issue this command:

```
org-narrow-to-subtree
```

As documented, it narrows the buffer to the current subtree. Now how do I un-narrow it ? I tried things like:

- org-show-subtree
- org-show-block-all

But nothing seem to bring the original buffer back. I can of-course kill the buffer and open the file again, but I think there would be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`(widen)` is enough for it, there is no need of an specialized function.

Usually bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

Also, you may find interesting those parts from the manuals:

- [Narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) from the Emacs Manual.
- [narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Narrowing.html) from Elisp Reference Manual.